# GCC doesn't link static library dependency (makefile)

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, linker

I use a static library, let's assume cityhash, which I've build and installed to /usr/local/lib. I have a file foo.cxx which uses cityhash, for example:

```
// foo.cxx
u64 get_hash(const std::string &s) {
  return CityHash64(s.data(), s.size());
}
```

I build a static library from it:

```
gcc -c foo.cxx  => foo.o
ar rcs libfoo.a foo.a  => libfoo.a
```

I have another file, bar.cxx, which uses foo.cxx and indirectly CityHash function. I compile it, and link with both libcityhash.a and libfoo.a like the following:

```
gcc -c bar.cxx  => bar.o
gcc -L. -o bar bar.o -lcityhash -lfoo
```

But this doesn't work, linker complains that CityHash64 is undefined reference. What is wrong? When I do not make a static library `libfoo.a` everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this. You need to write linker args `-lfoo -lcityhash`. Library that needs symbol should go before the one that provides it.

[Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)